# BlackBerry 10 - Invoking Browser

Tags: blackberry-10

Are there any examples of invoking the BlackBerry 10 browser to open on an `onclick` event? I'm trying to do this with the native SDK using c++.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## HTML5

Taken from the sample [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.invoke.html#.invoke):

```
function openWebLink() {
    // open web link - allows the system to choose an appropriate target that handles http://
    blackberry.invoke.invoke({
        uri: "http://www.blackberry.com"
    }, onInvokeSuccess, onInvokeError);
}

function openWebLinkInBrowser() {
    // open web link in browser
    blackberry.invoke.invoke({
        target: "sys.browser",
        uri: "http://www.blackberry.com"
    }, onInvokeSuccess, onInvokeError);
}
```

## Native

Using the following [attributes](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/invocation/browser.html)...

### Cascades

An example is available [here](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/invokeclient)

### Pure

Use [navigator_invoke.h](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/bb10/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/topic/about_navigator__invoke_8h.html)

```
navigator_invoke_invocation_t *invoke = NULL;
navigator_invoke_invocation_create(&invoke);

navigator_invoke_invocation_set_target(invoke, "sys.browser");
navigator_invoke_invocation_set_action(invoke, "bb.action.OPEN");
navigator_invoke_invocation_set_uri(invoke, "http://stackoverflow.com");

navigator_invoke_invocation_send(invoke);
navigator_invoke_invocation_destroy(invoke);
```

Comment: this is great for HTML5/Webworks. I need to do this in native code, so in C++.

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover native. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: for Pure, what do i need to include?

Answer (score 2):

Include Qt library and call

```
Qt.openUrlExternally(targetUri);
```